# Blazor (Server) Model Complex Validation doesn't work in EditForms with EditContext

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to validate my models inside a DTO on my Blazor Server App (currently .NET 8), but `editforms` with `EditContext`, do not seem to validate them.

I have a model named `ProdATransaction`, which is the header or the master model.

This model will be filled on the *Create page*, then on the DTO will be on the *Edit Page*, which consists of 3 models, the `ProductATransaction`, `ClientInfo` and `ItemDetails`.

Here are my models:

```cs
public class TransactionBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title field is required.")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description field is required.")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int StatusTypeId { get; set; }
    public StatusType? StatusType { get; set; }
}

public class TypeBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage= "Name field is required.")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}


public class ActionType : TypeBase
{
}

public class StatusType: TypeBase
{

}

public class ProdATransaction : TransactionBase
{
    public int ActionTypeId { get; set; }
    public ActionType? ActionType { get; set; }

}

public class ClientInfo : TypeBase
{
    public int ProdATransactionId { get; set; }
    public ProdATransaction? ProdATransaction { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address field is required")]
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public string? ContactPerson { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDetails : TypeBase
{
    public int ProdATransactionId { get; set; }
    public ProdATransaction? ProdATransaction { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string? Remarks { get; set; }
}

public class ProdATransactionDT
{
    public ProdATransaction ProdATransaction { get; set; }
    public ClientInfo ClientInfo { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDetails> ItemDetails { get; set; }
}
```

When the `EditContext` has been validated, it returns true as the `ProdATransaction` is not null, but the rest are null, and the list count is zero.

I'm trying to use Kudvenkat's Complex Model Validation, but it seems that the `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` is still on pre-release.

How can I validate the fields on DTOs?